# Label text ignoring html tags

Tags: html

```
<label for="abc" id="xyz">http://abc.com/player.js</xref>?xyz="foo" </label>
```

is ignoring

```
</xref> tag
```

value in the browser. So, the displayed output is

```
http://abc.com/player.js?xyz="foo"
```

but i want the browser to display

```
http://abc.com/player.js</xref>?xyz="foo"
```

Please help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the question, I thought the URI was to be used elsewhere within JavaScript. But the question pretty clearly states that the URI is to just be rendered as text.

If the text being displayed is being passed in from a server, then your best bet is to encode it before printing it on the page (or if you're using a template engine, then you can most likely just encode it on the template). Pretty much any web framework/templating engine should have this functionality.

However, if it is just static HTML, just manually encode the the characters. If you don't know the codes off the top of your head, you can just use some online converter to help, such as something like:

**HTML Encode/Decode:**
http://htmlentities.net/

---

**Old Answer:**

Try encoding the URI using the JavaScript function `encodeURI` before using it:

```
encodeURI('http://abc.com/player.js</xref>?xyz="foo"');
```

You can also decode it using `decodeURI` if need be:

```
decodeURI(yourEncodedURI);
```

So ultimately I don't think you'll be able to get the browser to display the `</xref>` tag as is, but you will be able to preserve it (using `encodeURI`/`decodeURI`) and use it in your code, if this is what you need.

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/rk8nR/3/

**More info:**
[When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

Comment: Why would you use client-side scripting for just escaping “<” in markup the proper way?

Comment: lol @user835785 the HTML section doesn't in the least bit contribute.

Comment: @user835785 I've heavily modified my answer, please reconsider who's answer is best for you.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't being ignored. It is being treated as an end tag (for a non-HTML element that has no start tag). Use `&lt;` if you want a `<` character to appear as data instead of as "start of tag".

That said, this is a URL and raw `<`, `>` and `"` characters shouldn't appear in URIs anyway. So encode it as `http://abc.com/player.js%3C/xref%3E?xyz=%22foo%22`

Comment: Thanks, is there any js library function that does this?

Comment: `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent` are part of core JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this

```
"http://abc.com/player.js%3C/xref%3E?xyz=foo"
```

Url should be encoded properly to work as valid URL

Use `encodeURI` for encoding URLs for a valid one

```
var ValidURL = encodeURI("http://abc.com/player.js</xref>?xyz=foo");
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3608791/1432033) answer on `encodeURI` for better knowledge.